# checkbox click event is not working in android 4.4.2

Tags: android, checkbox, android-4.4-kitkat, android-relativelayout

CheckBox click event is not working in android 4.4.2

```
holder.addcheck.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Testing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Your code is not sufficient to understand your problem. Please post some more code along with your selector code.

Comment: why use `isSelected` in the first place though?

Comment: Where you have applied your selector in your xml file?

Comment: Remove the `android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` line from your CheckBox.

Comment: no that is xml file can you please check above i have edited file name

Comment: pass the context in the toast not getApplication context ,pass the context of the Activity or fragment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [checkbox click event is not working in android 4.4.2 and above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25658419/checkbox-click-event-is-not-working-in-android-4-4-2-and-above)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your selector for `CheckBox` as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/defaultTick" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/greentick" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/defaultTick"/> <!-- default -->

</selector>
```

Change your condition as below:

```
if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
    String str = checkBox.getTag().toString();                                      
    checkBox.setChecked(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using setOnCheckedChangeListener().
Below is a code snippet.

```
holder.addcheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new   CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Testing"+isChecked,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```